# Image moves depending on browser

Tags: image

This is driving me mad and I am 100% you have all see it before. I therefore think I am doing a basic error but can't find another post on it.

I have a small image which is in a different position depending which browser you use. The two browsers I am testing with are Chrome and IE.

Here is the code:

```
#stu_outer_hot3 {
position: relative;
top: 389px;
left: 320px;
}
#stu_hot3
position:absolute;
left: 0px;
height: 96px;
width: 84px;
}
```

Here is the page: http://www.rigol-uk.co.uk/category/products3/digital-oscilloscopes/

The image is the yellow HOT triangle.

Any pointers would help a LOT!

Thanks in advance!
Stuart